How to make an image fixed using tailwindcss?
I'm encountering an issue in my React app while utilizing Tailwind CSS. When attempting to fix the image, it unexpectedly occupies the entire width of the screen. Moreover, the div with the class "col span-1" appears positioned behind it due to the fixed property. Could someone with experience in React and Tailwind CSS help me troubleshoot this problem? Any insights would be greatly appreciated!
<div className="h-[100vh]">
        <div className="lg:grid grid-cols-3 w-full h-full">
          <div className="col-span-2 h-full  lg:block hidden top-0 bg-gray-500  ">
            {" "}
            <div
              className="h-full bg-cover bg-center  top-0  left-0 bottom-0"
              style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${img})` }}
            ></div>
          </div>

          <div id="content-wraper" className="col-span-1 bg-white h-full    ">
            <div className="left-0 boor">salut</div>
            <div className="flex items-center justify-center">
              <div id="main-content" className=" max-w-sm h-full ">
                <div className=" flex items-center justify-center p-10">
                  <img
                    src={logo}
                    className="block btn- h-[50px]  w-auto "
                    alt=""
                  />
                </div>
                <div>
                  <h6 className="text-gray-800 font-semibold text-2xl mb-5 text-center ">
                    {" "}
                    Connexion
                  </h6>
                </div>
                <div className="mb-5">
                  {" "}
                  <IndexPage />
                  <Separator text="ou" />
                  <Boutton />
                </div>
                <div className="mb-5">
                  <p className=" font-light text-gray-400 text-center text-xs">
                    En continuant, vous acceptez les{" "}
                    <a className="font-medium ">Conditions d'Utilisation</a> et
                    la{" "}
                    <a className="font-medium ">
                      Politique de Confidentialité{" "}
                    </a>{" "}
                    de la société .
                  </p>
                </div>
                <div className=" flex flex-col justify-center items-center text-sm">
                  <p className="font-medium text-gray-800 ">
                    Vous n'êtes pas encore inscrit ?
                  </p>
                  <a
                    href="/auth/sign-up/default"
                    className=" font-medium text-yellow-500 "
                  >
                    Créer un compte
                  </a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>


You div with the background image by default has width: auto which means that it will expand to fill its contents. You instead want to restrict it's width to be that of its parents by setting w-full which sets width: 100% that ensures this restriction.

Even after applying the suggested solution, the issue persists. Do you have any other recommendations?
